# Android Listview: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android-listview, listviewitem

I am trying to create a list based on the listview elements and when I go beyond a certain amount of elements in a list and try to save, I get this error. Here is my code:

```
private void SaveList() {

        /** get all values of the EditText-Fields */
        View v;
        EditText et;
        TextView tv;
        for (int i = 0; i < lv.getCount(); i++) {
            v = lv.getChildAt(i);
            et = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.editid);
            tv = v.findViewById(R.id.field);

            EditModel saveDataItem = new EditModel(); //edit model is just an object containing values of the listview elements
            saveDataItem.setEditTextValue(et.getText().toString());
            saveDataItem.setFieldName(tv.getText().toString());

            saveList.add(saveDataItem);
        }

    }
```

And I declare savelist when the activity is created like this:

```
private ArrayList<EditModel> saveList = new ArrayList<>();
```

I do not get an error when the listview is less than the length 8

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I found a solution, I had to make sure that I use listview.getChildCount() instead of listview.getCount()